# File not found exception- text based files only

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

Full Edit: Right, I get the feeling that what I see to be obvious is not to someone not working on this project so this may annoy some people but I'm gonna reset the details here.

Originally:- 
I had a series of text files, image files and sound files that sat in my Eclipse IDE workspace. Whilst I ran the application from the IDE, everything was shiny. The text based files (.DAT in this instance) are being loaded use the File and Scanner classes (see below) and the images and Sound are being loaded by slick2d (see below):

```
// Loading a text based file from the IDE workspace
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("text/intro1.DAT"));

// Loading an image and a sound as handled by slick2d
Image background = new Image("images/backgrounds/menuBG.jpg");
Sound bgm = new Sound("sounds/music/MainMenuTheme.wav");
```

So far everything works, however...

Exporting:- When I exported the file to a runnable jar, none of the text, sounds and images were exported along with it. I did some research and learned that if things where contained within the /lib folder of the library would be exported. This had two effects:

- This broke ALL the links in the IDE. Seeing as everything now existed in ./lib/...

  HOWEVER, as the contents of lib are exported directly to the top level of the jar (at least when I do so with Eclipse and JarSplice as I am doing) this *fixed* the difference. At least before the problem I am trying to solve.

The Problem:- Looking at the code above, the text folder and the sounds folder exist at exactly the same level in the resulting exported jar. That and the path string has NOT been changed since the IDE where they both worked. Now, after being exported to a runnable jar ALL the sounds and image files are successfully loaded by slick2d but ALL of the text based (.DAT) files are now resulting in FileNotFound Exceptions at run time, even though the access for them has NOT been changed.

Obviously, there is not something wrong with the path in the direct sense as the images and sounds are still being loaded but the error still persists.

I am accessing the file in a wrong manner? Is there some sort of conflict between how slick2d manages itself and trying to access the files in the way I have?

Hope this is a little clearer.

Comment: Is the exception thrown only when you invoke the code from the jar file or also from your IDE?
Note that the 2 pieces of code that you posted are strictly equivalent, so this is normal to get the same behavior...

Comment: @Kira Namida I'd try outputting the current working directory and do a listing.

Comment: If the files are outside lib (i.e. in the eclipse workspace) the IDE finds them but the jar does not.
If they are in lib neither finds them. However, it wasn't until I added everything else to lib that they were successfully exported to the jar (everything that is, I have images and sounds in lib as well, but there are being loaded fine using the same use of sting paths. I have even put images into the folder "text" and loaded them from there).

Answer (score 0):

Since you said the files have moved I'm going to guess you would want something like this

```
File file = new File("lib/text/intro1.DAT");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("lib/text/intro1.DAT"));
```

Relative file paths (file paths that don't start with '/' or a drive letter) start at the root of the project/jar.

Comment: There is no lib file in my exported runnable jar file. Everything that is in lib in the eclipse IDE ends up in the top level of the jar as it's own folder at that level.

Answer (score 0):

When specifying relative paths to files, java interprets that relative path with respect to the current working directory. The current working directory is the place where you run the java command.

You should specify the location of your file with respect to this directory.

Example:

```
   File located at: drive1/files/yourfile
   java run in: drive1/aDir/

   In this case you should specify the file's location as: ./../files/yourfile
```

Comment: All my other files are loading correctly, it is only the non text file. Though this gives me a slight revelation. See update to question.

Comment: The update is not offering any new details. What's the location of the "other files"? How do you access them in the code ?